# Latex amsmath DeclareMathOperator

Tags: math-mode

In the short tutorial of **ShareLatex**, there is a sentence about `DeclareMathOperator`

> The command can be slightly modified if you need that your defined operator uses subscripts, as the `\lim` operator, in such case use `\DeclareMathOperator*`.

What does it mean? What is the difference between the starred and un-starred version of `DeclareMathOperator`?

Answer (score 17):

Here's the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\starred}{starred}
\DeclareMathOperator{\unstarred}{unstarred}
\begin{document}
\[\starred_{x=0}\quad\unstarred_{x=0}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can always override the index placement by putting `\limits` or `\nolimits` behind the operator. Oh, and in inline math, they both act as the unstarred version by default.

Comment: Thanks, this example demonstrates the difference really well!

Comment: I think that `\limits` or `\nolimits` should be put *after* the operator (and before `_`, of course).

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas That's what I meant. I figure “behind” and “after” are synonyms, but maybe they're not.